# The generating function of a conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, generating-functions

Here is a problem from a section in my stochastic processes textbook on branching processes:

> Let $\phi(s)$ be the generating function of an offspring random variable, $\xi$. Let $Z$ be a random variable whose distribution is that of $\xi$, but conditional on $\xi>0$. That is,
> $$\mathbb{P}(Z=k)=\mathbb{P}(\xi=k|\xi>0)$$
> Express the generating function for $Z$ in terms of $\phi$.

I'm rather new to probability generating functions, and I'm not too familiar with the techniques that we're supposed to use for problems like this. I didn't get very far:
$$\phi_z(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(Z=k)s^k=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(\xi=k|\xi>0)s^k$$
I'm not certain how to continue from this step at all. How would you guys complete this problem?

Comment: I don't know if there's a specific tool from generating functions to use here, but I'd start by writing $P(Z=k)$ in terms of $P(\xi = k)$ and $P(\xi = 0)$.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(Z=k)=0$ for $k=0$ while $\mathbb{P}(Z=k)= \frac{\mathbb{P}(\xi=k)}{1-\mathbb{P}(\xi=0)}$ for $k>0$.  So this is an easy manipulation (you just need to subtract and divide suitably)